# Can't get django 1.5.8 to serve static files in apps sub-directory

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

I have followed the doc for [Managing static files in django 1.5.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/)

> Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Done, and 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder' is in my STATICFILES_FINDERS

> In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Done

My HTML (for test) :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
"{% static 'selfcareapi/header_selfcare_api.png' %}"
```

Then

> Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg.

Here is my file organisation :

```
Project
|
|-selfcareapi
|    |
|    |-views.py
|    |-static
|        |
|        |-selfcareapi
|            |
|            |-header_selfcare_api.png
|-templates
    |
    |-selfcareapi
        |
        |-my_html.html
```

The rendered html give me

```
/static/selfcareapi/header_selfcare_api.png
```

Which seems OK.

When I runserver and go to : localhost/static/selfcareapi/header_selfcare_api.png, I have a 404 error...

Why does not runserver serve the static files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you serving from `runserver`?

If so, did you add this to you `urls.py`?

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Also make sure your app is in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Comment: Team issue here ^^ Whe are 5 to works on this project and the guy who did the app forgot to add it in INSTALLED_APPS and I forgot to check it.... Thanks twined !

Comment: What is the use of urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() ? It works for me without that !